# Вопрос о постановке запятой

Tags: пунктуация

Что из всего этого взяли для себя марки**, и** какими будут тенденции макияжа этой осенью?

Answer (score 2):

Это сложное предложение, состоящее из двух простых ВОПРОСИТЕЛЬНЫХ предложений, поэтому запятая между частями предложения не ставится

Answer (score 1):

Запятая между предложениями, соединёнными союзами И и ДА,ИЛИ, ЛИБО, не ставится, "если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей здесь оказывается интонация, а в побудительных предложениях могут быть и общие частицы: Где будет собрание и кто его председатель? — общая вопросительная интонация; Как тихо вокруг и как чисто звездное небо! — общая восклицательная интонация; Пусть светит солнце и птицы поют! — общая частица".[Лопатин](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=132)